# Passing arguments with signals and slots in qt

Tags: c++, qt

I am new to qt and i have got a question.

I wanted to connect signals and slots.

```
QObject::connect(_Requests, SIGNAL(newJobsAvailable(const MyClass &)), _Object, SLOT(doSend(const MyClass &)));
```

The qt complains about not being able to queue `MyClass` and etc.

How do i declare it correctly with

```
qRegisterMetaType<const MyClass &>("const MyClass&");
```

Comment: you should send an explicit pointer instead of a const ref to conform to the Qt standard

Comment: ratchet freak: Not sure what you mean. Passing value-type arguments via pointer is definitely a bad idea, and const refs. work just fine (and are the best option, in most cases).

Comment: This isn't the problem, but names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_Requests`, `_Object`) and names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved to the implementation (the compiler and its library). Don't use them.

Answer (score 1):

If Qt complains about not being able to queue you class this means that, Qt is unable to copy and put inside QVariant object of your class.
This only means that only direct connection will work. What does it mean? If you are using default value of last argument in `connect` then connection will not work between threads!
Setting last argument of `connect` to `Qt::DirectConnection` should silence the warning, and value `Qt::QueuedConnection` will not work at all.

Another way to fix it is to register your type. But you should do this without any qualifiers!

```
qRegisterMetaType<MyClass>("MyClass");
```

If you are using Qt5 then consider use of Q_GADGET macro in `MyClass` (just put it in beginning of class definition and add header to HEADERS in pro file).

Comment: You should add that Q_DECLARE_METATYPE() is also needed

Comment: Nope. With this version of `qRegisterMetaType` it is not required. Version without typeName parameter requiters Q_DECLARE_METATYPE. See [doc](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmetatype.html#qRegisterMetaType).

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that `MyClass` has ***public*** default and copy constructors. Because the object might be copied, even if you declare signals and slots with `const ref`.

If for some reason copy is out of the question then pass pointer as suggested by ratchet